# Unsort a listbox in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I am very new programmer, the user is able to input vales into a `ListBox`, there is also a option button where the user can sort the numbers in ascending order. However I am also asked to create a option  button to unsort back into its original form, however I am not sure how I would do this. I am trying to do this without the use of any containers/arrays. here is my code to sort:

```
private void sorted()
{
    int a = lstHoldValue.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < a - 1; i++)
    {
        var k = 0;
        for (var j = 1; j < a - i; j++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]) < Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[k]))
            {
                var temp = lstHoldValue.Items[j];
                lstHoldValue.Items[j] = lstHoldValue.Items[k];
                lstHoldValue.Items[k] = temp;
                k = j;
            }
            else
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to store to orginal list somewhere as 'unsorting' is never possible. I suspect you are not allowed to use the system sort? (Linq: OrderBy)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  The general rule around here is that you have to try something yourself first, which you clearly have, and if it doesn't work then explain what it is doing wrong.  We will look at specific issues for you, but not recommend solutions to an open problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Any time you want to change the state of something, you need to be able to define the intended target state.  So if you want to "unsort" something, then you need to know what the intended "unsorted" order it.  You have to store that information somewhere when you have it.

Comment: if your items would have it`s current position number stored in it, you would be able to show original order.

Comment: @TaW  yeah that's correct, I am not allowed to use the system sort

Comment: How can I store it without a container ?

Comment: just create a new one: `// save a copy:
            var itemCopy = lb.Items.Cast<object>().ToArray();
            // restore:
            lb.Items.Clear();
            lb.Items.AddRange( itemCopy.Cast<object>().ToArray());`

Comment: thanks for the kind response, but isnt this doing it with an array? as i am not allowed to